# Mirth Connect channelMap.size

Tags: javascript, size, mirth

I need the string lenght inside a channelmap. I found the channelMap.size method already, but..

```
DETAILS:    Can't find method com.mirth.connect.server.userutil.ChannelMap.size(string).
at 7b0f55d4-9758-4764-8486-6b0363f598c5:75 (doTransform)
at 7b0f55d4-9758-4764-8486-6b0363f598c5:101 (doScript)
at 7b0f55d4-9758-4764-8486-6b0363f598c5:103
at com.mirth.connect.server.transformers.JavaScriptFilterTransformer$FilterTransformerTask.doCall(JavaScriptFilterTransformer.java:154)
at com.mirth.connect.server.transformers.JavaScriptFilterTransformer$FilterTransformerTask.doCall(JavaScriptFilterTransformer.java:119)
at com.mirth.connect.server.util.javascript.JavaScriptTask.call(JavaScriptTask.java:113)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, how can i get the string lenght inside a channelmap.

Answer (score 2):

```
var strLen = channelMap.get('var').length
```

seems to be the easiest way.

Comment: Any time you pull a string out of a Map, it will always be converted to a java.lang.String, even if you stuck a Javascript String in there to begin with. On java strings, `length()` is a method, and not a property (so you'll need the parentheses.)